# LDAP Authentication on Apache Livy

Tags: authentication, ldap, livy

How do I enable LDAP Authentication on Apache Livy? I have seen the following resources but I haven't found anything that documents how to utilize the commits:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LIVY-356
- https://github.com/apache/incubator-livy/pull/231

I'm fairly new to Apache Livy and I'd really appreciate any leads I can get.

Answer (score 0):

by org.apache.livy.LivyConf
you can find the configuration

```scala
  val AUTH_TYPE = Entry("livy.server.auth.type", null)
  // Ldap configurations
  val AUTH_LDAP_URL = Entry("livy.server.auth.ldap.url", null)
  val AUTH_LDAP_BASE_DN = Entry("livy.server.auth.ldap.base-dn", null)
  val AUTH_LDAP_USERNAME_DOMAIN = Entry("livy.server.auth.ldap.username-domain", null)
  val AUTH_LDAP_ENABLE_START_TLS = Entry("livy.server.auth.ldap.enable-start-tls", "false")
  val AUTH_LDAP_SECURITY_AUTH = Entry("livy.server.auth.ldap.security-authentication", "simple")
```